# Stateful function pointer for passing C++ capturing lambdas / std::functions to C style callbacks

Tags: c++, c, c++17, pointers, callback

```cpp
#include <functional>

template<typename return_type, typename... argument_types>
struct stateful_function_pointer
{
  using function_type         = std::function<return_type(argument_types...)>;
  using function_pointer_type = return_type (*) (argument_types..., void*);

  function_pointer_type callback ()
  {
    return [ ] (argument_types... arguments, void* user_data)
    {
      return (*static_cast<function_type*>(user_data))(arguments...);
    };
  }
  void*                 user_data()
  {
    return static_cast<void*>(&function);
  }

  function_type function;
};
```

The C style callback must be providing a `void*` user data as its final parameter (which is a de-facto standard). It may be possible to pass additional user data other than the function state, but I do not see the point as the lambda can already capture user state.

An eccentricity: It is instantiated as e.g. `stateful_function_pointer<void, int, char*>` instead of `stateful_function_pointer<void(int, char*)>`.

Example usage as requested (wrapping a HDF5 C function in C++):

```
class link_access_property_list : public property_list
{
public:
  using function_pointer_type = stateful_function_pointer<herr_t, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, unsigned*, hid_t>;
  using callback_type = function_pointer_type::function_type;

  bool set_external_link_callback(const callback_type& callback)
  {
    function_pointer_.function = callback;
    return H5Pset_elink_cb(id_, function_pointer_.callback(), function_pointer_.user_data()) >= 0;
  }

protected:
  function_pointer_type function_pointer_;
};
```

Then I could:

```
lapl.set_external_link_callback(
  [CAPTURE_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT] 
  (const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, unsigned*, hid_t) 
  { 
    USE_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT 
    return herr_t(0);
  });
```

Comment: On the other end how do you intend to cast the `void*` back to its original type if you don't know the type information?

Comment: Please show us the C function you are using to convert this back. Also an example of how you think the callback is being used would be helpful.

Comment: This allows you to capture arbitrary state into the C callback via lambda closures. You don't cast anything. You capture what you need.

Comment: But the callback is a C function. The only thing it knows is `void*`. So you have to convert it to a `void*` at some point and then you need to convert it back to the original type. You can't pass a lambda to be registered as a C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a C callback you usually pass two things

- A pointer to a C function
- A `void*` pointer that is passed to your C function.

The C function must know the type of the original object so it can cast the pointer back to its original type. only after it has been cast back can it be used. And you must cast it back to the exact type it was before you converted to `void*` or you are in undefined behavior.

So this means the C function must understand the original type.

Since your original type is a templated type (i.e. you don't know the type in general) you can't cast it back (unless you templitize the function so that the function you pass to C has a understanding of the templitized types).

The easy way to do this is to implement a virtual interface. Then you can get a pointer to the base class convert this to a `void*` then in the C function you can convert back to the base class pointer and call the appropriate virtual interface on this base pointer. Virtual dispatch will then take care of calling the correct implementation.

---

OK found the reference you were eluding to:

Next time just add it to the question.

From: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.8/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetELinkCb

```
herr_t elink_callback(const char* parent_file_name,
                      const char* parent_group_name,
                      const char* child_file_name,
                      const char* child_object_name,
                      unsigned*   acc_flags,
                      hid_t       fapl_id,
                      void*       op_data)
{
    puts(child_file_name);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    hid_t lapl_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_LINK_ACCESS);
    H5Pset_elink_cb(lapl_id, elink_callback, NULL);
    ...
}
```

Notice at the top of the document it talks about C functions: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.8/RM/RM_H5P.html

This library is robably built by a C compiler so the whole ABI is a C ABI. Thus you can not pass any functions of C++ linkage as a parameter to a callback (The C code does not know how to correctly set up the stack frame to make a correct C++ call). You can only pass functions with C linkage.

Now some compilers use a very similar ABI for C and C++ and you may get lucky passing a function that uses C++ linkage, but that just means you are getting lucky.

Things like exceptions (that's just the first thing I can think of) will not be properly tracked across the stack frame boundries when going into C built stack frame.

As you are getting lucky it is likely that sometime in the future it will just suddenly stop working with no way to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @demiralp Obviously I am not understanding your usage. Can you provide an exact example of it being used in some code. Personally I am still doubtful this will work. But I could be wrong and it will depend on the interfaces it is being used in.

Comment: What is this: `lapl.set_external_link_callback()` This does not look like a C callback interface.

Comment: @demiralp Found the docs for HP5 stuff: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.8/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetELinkCb OK. It becomes clearer now. I pretty sure that is broken code. Note: There is a difference between working and **working by accident**. The `H5Pset_elink_cb()` call takes a C-function as an argument. Unfortunately you are not giving it a C-function (as you are passing a variadic template function). There is no gurantee provided by the C++ standard that a C++ function has the same ABI as a C function.

Comment: @demiralp To make this valid the function passed to `H5Pset_elink_cb()` **MUST** be declared as `extern "C" herr_t <funcName>(const char*,const char*,const char*,const char*, unsigned*, hid_t,void*)`. Sure you may be getting lucky but that does not make it legal or valid. Currently it is simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @demiralp: `The compilers must be creating multiple definitions of lambdas, one with and one without extern "C"?` definitely not. The code is simply undefined behavior. It works by accident.

Comment: **hypothetical problem**: No its a real problem. It's a real enough problem that they actually tell you how to solve it in the article you linked. You have three compilers on a single architecture using probably only one set of flags. I don't think you have enough context to "agree" with anybody. Your ability to test this is simply too limited.

Comment: @demiralp That's not even a reasonable test. The problem here is that the code you would be linking with the i.e `H5P` library would be compiled with a C compiler (this is C code after all if they could use C++ feature it would be compiler with a C++ compiler). Now link that C library against your C++ code.

Comment: `Does anyone really use anything other than Clang/GCC/MSVC today?`: Yes. Every SOC chip will have its own custom compiler.

Comment: @demiralp All those hardware manafactures out there are shit out of luck then. So you have only worked in environments with Linux or Windows servers installed. i.e. small metal shops. These places tend to use bottom end machines and get scale by horizontal scaling. At the other end of the spectrum you have big metal machines that get scale by vertical scaling. Think of any big hardware manufacturer that also has its own OS they have their own C++ compiler: IBM => AIX => xlC++, HP => HP UX => aC++, Cray => COS => BlueWaters etc

Comment: I worked for Veritas (now part of Symantic). We built key management software.  We sold this to other manufacturers. Our code had to build on all platforms we supported. A platform was `Hardware/OS-V/Compiler-V`. I seem to remember we supported over 36 different combinations of platform. If you code was not 100% standard compliant (and even using obscure features was not a good idea) you were going to break on one or more platforms.

Comment: Linux/Windows were the simplest of these platforms as they did not tend to beak backward compatibility (apart from gcc.2.95 to gcc.3.01) moving between versions and hardware/OS/Compiler. Most other OS were not as forgiving and each version of the compiler was unique and had different bugs.